# OO paradigm and encapsulated instance variables in Perl5

Tags: oop, variables, instance, perl

I need a way to make really encapsulated variables in Perl, without using any frameworks like Moose, so that you can access the instance variables only through getters and setters. There should be private instance variables.

The subroutines respectively methods are not a problem, because you can define them so that they can be used just through an instance respectively a reference. But variables you can always access via the package name, like class-vars.

Is there any way to prevent that?

Comment: I have edited your question to make it more readable. Please check to make sure it is still correct. But I'm afraid I have never heard of a *resp. variable*; what do you mean by that?

Comment: It was a mistake, there are not any resp. vars. What i mean is that you can always call perl-variable throw the package-name (class-name) and in a same time throw an instance and this is to example in Java not possible, an instance variable is a instance variable and a class variable is a class variable, maybe i fail my question a little bit, so to complete it, i would like to have real private instance variable in perl.

Comment: @DenisKomnenovic s/throw/through/ unless I'm mistaken. Edited your Q.

Comment: After several attempts to ask what you want to achieve and why, I have to mark this question as ***unclear what you're asking***

Comment: Before you go down the wrong path, do read [David Golden's excellent presentation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35828756/100754) linked from my answer.

Comment: Download an appropriate package from CPAN. Don't reinvent (and re-debug) code. You'll save time, money, and frustration. And you'll get security patches for issues you don't even know exist. :)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're trying to prevent people from accessing the instance variables other than through the accessors; is that right?

Perl is a language for polite people, and the way you stop programmers from doing things you don't want them to do is to ask them not to. Yes, there are hacks, and the most obvious one here would be to make each object a closure ([here's an article about it from the Perl Journal](http://www.foo.be/docs/tpj/issues/vol4_3/tpj0403-0010.html)) but there are almost always ways around them, so you won't be able to stop the determined impertinent hacker

One of [Larry Wall's excellent attributions](https://www.goodreads.com/author/quotes/89118.Larry_Wall) is this, which explains my point superbly

> Perl doesn't have an infatuation with enforced privacy. It would prefer that you stayed out of its living room because you weren't invited, not because it has a shotgun

Comment: Can someone *please* let me know if the Perl Journal is not freely accessible? I was surprised  that I couldn't find a "proper" public URL for its content. Thanks

Comment: Konkov and Borodin: Thanks guys, you help me a lot, with this few answers. I try to implement some kind of netbeans-convention and factory-pattern and other stuffs in Perl, a way like i would do in Java and without any frameworks. Of course not directly like in Java, but you now what i mean. Thanks.

Comment: @DenisKomnenovic: I'm sorry that you never chose to explain what you were hoping to achieve. This is clearly an [X Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/), but we were never given the chance to address the underlying issue, and you got some very vague responses when we had to guess at your purpose

Comment: Sorry, but i have to finish some prog. - tasks today and i have not so much time, next time i will write some examples. Cheers.

Comment: @DenisKomnenovic: It's not so much code examples that I wanted, but more an insight into what these *"really encapsulated variables"* were for. It's always better to ask for a solution to the underlying problem than to invent a partial solution and ask how to implement that. If, as I suspect, you're hoping to prevent unauthorised people hacking your code then I promise you're wasting your time. With proper data security, the worst a persistent hacker can do is crash your system. Code security is pointless

Answer (score 2):

People tried to achieve this kind of thing with *inside out objects*. [This presentation by David Golden](http://www.dagolden.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/20060117_whats_all_the_fuss.pdf) explains it perfectly:

> - Inside-out objects first presented by Dutch Perl hacker Abigail in 2002
> - Spring 2002 – First mention at Amsterdam.pm,
> - June 28, 2002 – YAPC NA "Two alternative ways of doing OO"
> - July 1, 2002 – First mention on Perlmonks
> - Gained recent attention (notoriety?) as a recommended best practice with the publication of Damian Conway's Perl Best Practices
> - Despite their benefits, they bring significant complexity and are not universally welcomed

There are a [number of modules](https://metacpan.org/search?size=20&q=inside%20out&search_type=modules) that try to facilitate this type of programming.

I find them rather cumbersome, and they have since fallen out of favor.

You can also find them mentioned in [perldoc perlobj](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlobj#Inside-Out-objects):

> In the past, the Perl community experimented with a technique called "inside-out objects". An inside-out object stores its data outside of the object's reference, indexed on a unique property of the object, such as its memory address, rather than in the object itself. This has the advantage of enforcing the encapsulation of object attributes, since their data is not stored in the object itself.
>
> This technique was popular for a while (and was recommended in Damian Conway's Perl Best Practices), but never achieved universal adoption. The `Object::InsideOut` module on CPAN provides a comprehensive implementation of this technique, and you may see it or other inside-out modules in the wild.

Answer (score -2):

To do really private variables you should use closures:

```
{
    my $x;

    sub get {
        return $x;
    }

    sub set {
        $x =  shift;
    }
}

set( 3 );
print get(); # prints 3
print $x; # ERROR

# Example with objects
package Class;

sub new {
    bless {}, 'Class';
}
{
    my $storage =  {};

    sub get {
        $self =  shift;
        return $storage->{ "$self" };            
    }

    sub set {
        $self =  shift;
        $storage->{ "$self" } =  shift;
    }
}

package main;
print Class::x; #ERROR

$z = Class::new();
$z->set( 3 );

$y = Class::new();
$y->set( 5 );
print $y->get(); # 5
print $z->get(); # 3
```

The `$x` is local to the block. None except `set` and `get` may access it.
"$self" will be like "Class=HASH(0x1cf9160)". Because of each object has its own address in memory "$self" will never collision.

But actually you are not required to do so in other case that will be **a stick in your wheel**

Comment: This looks nice, thanks for the advice. But i get still the problem, that i can call this variable using the package name (class name), but i would like to have real private "instance" variable. Now i thing, maybe i should define the getters in a way, that they just allow a reference/instance call. Eugen thanks so fare.

Comment: Your `set` and `get` aren't methods, and even if you allow for you forgetting to write `my $self = shift` then your $x is a *class variable* that is shared with every object created in the same class

Comment: @DenisKomnenovic: No, you can't access variables declared with `my` using the package. They are not package variables. Please explain what problem you are trying to solve. Are you hoping to defend yourself against hackers, or just bad programming?

Comment: @DenisKomnenovic Nope. You can not refer $x variable in my example with package like $Pkg::x . You miss something. Please post examples.

Comment: @EugenKonkov: I think that the issue of whether or not `$x` can be accessed using a package name is irrelevant since you haven't written a proper class. Show something that has a `new` method that I can call to return an object with `set` and `get` methods

Comment: @EugenKonkov: You're digging yourself a deeper hole. You've clearly "seen this somewhere" and never used it. Your solution doesn't contain any code that I can copy and run (you still don't have a `new`) and, as I said before, every instance would share what was `$x` and is now `$storage`

Comment: @Borodin: What problems you have with code? I run it without problem and private values are not shared between objects.

Comment: @EugenKonkov: This will be my last comment. You're now using the hash referred to by `$storage` (a class variable, so the block is unnecessary) but indexing it by the *stringification* of the hash reference that is assigned to each object. So you're using `{}` to create unique object IDs like `HASH(0x6bc300)`. That is one way of doing things, but it doesn't answer the OP's problem and it's pretty nasty

Comment: `{}` we require to restrict access only to `get/set` in other case other class methods in this file will have access to `$storage`.